# pandas not updating using Anaconda(spyder)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, spyder

Whilst debugging an error I found that my pandas library was very out of date v1.0.5 compared to the latest 1.5.xx so I tried to update it in the Spyder consol with:

`!pip install upgrade pandas`

I updated numpy at the same time which seemed to work fine. However now, ever time I try to import pandas I get the following errors and warning:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.__version__
print(x)
```

returns:

```
runfile('C:/Users/user/Documents/Scripts Python/L2C_data_project/Reed_api_testing.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/user/Documents/Scripts Python/L2C_data_project')
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_testing.py:24: FutureWarning: In the future 
'np.bool' will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.  (This may have returned Python 
scalars in past versions.
  import pandas._libs.testing as _testing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Scripts Python\L2C_data_project\Reed_api_testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    import pandas.testing

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas._testing import (

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.testing as _testing

  File "pandas\_libs\testing.pyx", line 10, in init pandas._libs.testing

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 284, in __getattr__
    def _expired(*args, **kwds):

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'
```

I cant run pandas at all now. It always just repeats the same warnings over and over, sometimes multiple times from the same code. I realise now that doing !pip install was not the best idea from within a conda enviroment and that I should probably have done

```
conda update pandas
```

I tried this recently and it did seem to do something, but it hasn't actually updated the package in "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages" In there I still have a "pandas" folder and a "pandas-1.0.5.dist-info" folder. So it looks like nothing has been updated as far as I can see, my anaconda seems to think that this is the most up to date version out there or something. I am not sure what do to as this point.

running `!pip install update pandas` just returns that there are no possible updates available.

Should I delete the "1.0.5.dist" folder and try to re install pandas via conda?

Should I just download the latest version of pandas from the officail site and simply add it to my "site-packages" folder with all of my other libraries.

I don't know what the best course of action is as I don't want to make everthing worse.

Comment: Did you run `conda update pandas` in the same environment that you using to run your code? Do you update pandas from the Anaconda Prompt or terminal?

Comment: I ran conda update pandas from within the spyder consol where my code usually outputs to.