# Python importing pandas as pd error in _testing.py

Tags: python, pandas, testing, anaconda3

When trying to import pandas as pd i get the following error in Jupyter notebook:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_testing.py:24: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  import pandas._libs.testing as _testing
```

I have a local Anaconda3 installation running. I am sitting on Windows 10 behind a corporate firewall. Deinstalling/Reinstalling just the pandas package with conda didn't work. Maybe someone has a solution to change a local .py file. The old solutions which i found on stack overflow are not working for me.

[image: Error when trying to import pandas]

[image]

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but this is a warning.    Somewhat akin to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779374/deprecationwarning-np-bool

Comment: It shows up as a warning but all following commands which should use pd* are not working. So it seems that pandas is not working.

Comment: Please include your errors and traceback as text and not as images.

Comment: [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: A similar report from a few months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75547795/12846804
Have you recently updated pandas?
On Numpy side: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67779374/12846804
Suggesting mismatching modules versions? Bad Anaconda environment? Please print your `pd.__version__` and `np.__version__`

Comment: I will force a complete reinstallation with my admin. Nothing works currently. Thanks for the answers.